# $\sum\nolimits_{i=0}^{\infty }{\sum\nolimits_{j=0}^{\infty }{\sum\nolimits_{k=0}^{\infty }{{{3}^{-\left( i+j+k \right)}}}}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

Some said to use Residue theorem (Special case for series )

S=$\sum\nolimits_{i=0}^{\infty }{\sum\nolimits_{j=0}^{\infty }{\sum\nolimits_{k=0}^{\infty }{{{3}^{-\left( i+j+k \right)}}}}}$  for $i\ne j\ne k$

My question is there any shortcut ??

Comment: for this kind of summation,  variables are independent, so you can get the summation by one variable and one variable.

Comment: Are you sure they are independent? Because there is a i≠j≠k condition.

Answer (score 7):

You can avoid inclusion-exclusion by considering $S$  as a nested sum:
$$S=6\sum_{i=0}^\infty 3^{-i}\sum_{j=i+1}^\infty 3^{-j}\sum_{k=j+1}^\infty 3^{-k}\ ,$$
whereby the factor $6$ compensates for the assumption $i<j<k$. The innermost sum has the value $$3^{-j}\sum_{k'=1}^\infty 3^{-k'}={1\over2} 3^{-j}\ .$$
The next-inner sum then becomes
$${1\over2}\sum_{j=i+1}^\infty3^{-2j}={1\over2}3^{-2i}\sum_{j'=1}^\infty 3^{-2j'}={1\over2}\cdot{1\over8}\>3^{-2i}\ .$$
In this way we finally obtain
$$S=6\cdot{1\over2}\cdot{1\over8}\sum_{i=0}^\infty 3^{-3i}=6\cdot{1\over2}\cdot{1\over8}\cdot{27\over26}={81\over208}\ .$$

Answer (score 6):

$$\sum\nolimits_{i=0}^{\infty }{\sum\nolimits_{j=0}^{\infty }{\sum\nolimits_{k=0}^{\infty }{{{3}^{-\left( i+j+k \right)}}}}} = \sum\nolimits_{i=0}^{\infty }{3}^{-i}{\sum\nolimits_{j=0}^{\infty }{3}^{-j}{\sum\nolimits_{k=0}^{\infty }{3}^{-k}}}\\ =\left(\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{1}{3^i}\right)^3 = \left(\frac{1}{1-1/3}\right)^3$$

Comment: the answer is not $\frac{27}{8}$  in my lecture notes 
since $i , j ,k$ are distinct

Comment: @RamezHindi, It doesn't make since to make global conditions on the summation indices because these variables can take any positive value.

Comment: @RamezHindi WolframAlpha finds the sum to be 27/8 as well. Maybe an error in your notes or in the copying of the problem?

Comment: @CodeLabMaster Did you include the fact that we are to have $i\ne j\ne k$?  And to the answerer, this is a wonderful answer (except that one thing) +1

Comment: @Simple Art , let us assume that the question was instead that i=j=k. Will that make any sense?

Comment: @SimpleArt No, I missed that. Good catch. Easy enough to amend, luckily.

Answer (score 3):

Since you want all the variables to be distinct, we can sum it over all values of i,j,k then subtract the sum that occurs when they are not distinct, and apply PIE(Principle of Inclusion/Exclusion).

Can you take it from there?